# Added jQuery UI and JQuery Mobile cdns to project but themes won;t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, themes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mileTracker.css">

<script src="jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"></script>
<script src="mileTracker.js"></script>

<header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Tracker</h1>
</header>
```

This is code that I have and I just can't seem to get the theme to be applied to the html code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears you have the Style sheets and jquery loaded locally, not via CDN. Please confirm that the files exist in the proper relative path and have the proper permissions.

Comment: Can confirm they are there locally even with the CDN links the problem persists. The only solution that I keep coming across is that some are sating the jQuery UI and Mobile seem to be not working well together. Would like to know if anyone has experienced this? I'm trying out different things to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that allows for the set-up to work, the css links were added after the jQuery mobile css link.

Also when using the jQuery links, the mobile css file was placed first followed by the 2 javascript files, first the jquery.min.js then the jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.js.

With the js files they were added after the css and in the order listed below.

Also I used a local deployment.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.css">    

    <script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/demos/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui-1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```